# Difference between @future and @future(callout=false)

Tags: apex

Is @future by default callout = false or true ?

Answer (score 4):

The default is callout=false. If you need to do a callout, you need to specify callout=true.

Comment: [Future Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm) doesn't tell you that false is the default, but a quick test would allow you to validate that this is indeed the case. I have submitted Feedback to the effect that this should be explicitly called out in the documentation.

Comment: As an aside, based on the question title, you might mention that @future and @future(callout=false) are exactly identical in nature.

Comment: Even though your answer is totally correct, I think it is also a good idea to add a link and a quote from an official documentation.